# VBO, Shader C++ Android Confusion

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, shader, vbo

I'm having trouble understanding where/how to setup buffers for a native android application in VS 2015. I apologize if this isn't the best way to ask a question. I appreciate any help/insight.

This is what I have so far:
(in engine_init_display)

```
GLint vShaderLength = vertex_shader.length();
const GLchar* vcode = vertex_shader.c_str();

GLint fShaderLength = fragment_shader.length();
const GLchar* fcode = fragment_shader.c_str();

GLuint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vs, 1, &vcode, NULL);
glCompileShader(vs);

GLuint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fs, 1, &fcode, NULL);
glCompileShader(fs);

shader_programme = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shader_programme, fs);
glAttachShader(shader_programme, vs);

glLinkProgram(shader_programme);

GLint pos_id = glGetAttribLocation(shader_programme, "position");

//Set vertex data
glUseProgram(shader_programme);

glVertexAttribPointer(pos_id, 0, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glVertexAttribPointer(pos_id, //GLuint
    3,    //GLint size
    GL_FLOAT,                             //GLenum type
    GL_FALSE,                             //GLboolean
    (sizeof(float) * 5),            //GLsizei stride
    points             //const GLvoid *pointer
    );


glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_id);
```

(in engine_draw_frame)

```
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.41f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);

eglSwapBuffers(engine->display, engine->surface);
```

With this, I get a pink (clear colour) background. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here are my vertex data and shaders

```
float points[] =
{
-0.2f, 0.6f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 1.0f,
0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 1.0f,
-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
0.0f, 0.0f,
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
1.0f, 0.0f
};

unsigned short indices[] =
{
0,  2,  1,  2,  3,  1
};

std::string vertex_shader =
"#version 300 es         \n"
"in vec3 position;        \n"
"void main () {            \n"
"  gl_Position = vec4 (position, 1.0); \n"
"} \n";

std::string fragment_shader =
"#version 300 es    \n"
"precision highp float; \n"
"out vec4 frag_colour; \n"
"void main () {        \n"
"  frag_colour = vec4 (0.5, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0); \n"
"}   \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. There isn't anything wrong with my shaders or vertex array. The problem was that I didn't specify EGL to create an OpenGLES2 context using EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION.

Check here -> [Khronos Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/specs/eglspec.1.4.20110406.pdf/), page 43 (of pdf) for more info

Sample from specification:

```
EGLContext eglCreateContext(EGLDisplay dpy,
          EGLConfig config, EGLContext share_context,
          const EGLint *attrib_list);
```

if the *attrib_list is left null, the default is OpenGLES1 and shaders will not work in that context.

So, what you need to do is create an attribute list. Something along the lines of:

```
EGLint contextAttributes[]=
{
    EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,2,
    EGL_NONE
}
```

and pass that to the create context

```
p_context = eglCreateContext(display, config, NULL, contextAttributes);
```

Basically, I was too unsure of my ability with vertex buffers that I focused on that for a long time.